# SQLITE query returns no result

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this query in my LoginAdapter class:

```
public Cursor FetchRow (String username){

  return db.query("LOGIN",new String[]{"ID","USERNAME","PASSWORD","COURSE","EMAIL","STUDENT_NAME"},"USERNAME" + "='" + username + "'",null,null,null,null);

}
```

When I call it from another activity the emulator opens the activity but with no results:

```
 String username = bundle.getString("username");

    loginDataBaseAdapter.FetchRow(username);
```

Comment: Have you checked are you passing proper username? in activity method.

Comment: Yes of course!! Has it anything to do with the fact that I don't have a text view in my activity to view the results??

Comment: Yes of course, how are you checking the result of your Sqlite query?

Comment: I don't!! I thought it would appear by default in the activity!!

Comment: Sorry no, easiest you can have is a toast message.

Comment: Can you suggest any modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a toast message as shown below:

```
String username = bundle.getString("username");

    String result = loginDataBaseAdapter.FetchRow(username);

Toast.makeText(this, "The value of result is " +result, Toast.Length_Long).show;
```

In your database message you can rewrite the query as shown below:

```
    public String FetchRow (String username){
    String result = null;

      Cursor cursor = db.query("LOGIN",new String[]{"ID","USERNAME","PASSWORD","COURSE","EMAIL","STUDENT_NAME"},"USERNAME =" '" + username + "'",null,null,null,null);
      if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

   result  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name_GIven_For_UserName_column");
    }
    return result;


    }
```

If the values are getting passed properly then you will get the answer. If you get any errors let me know. Add log messages after String username line of activity:

```
Log.d("Test", "The value of UserName is " +username);
```

This helps you in checking the user name value is correct or not.
After doing this you will receive a toast message in the activity if every thing is correct.

If you want the result to be viewed in textView then you need to define the textView in the xml and link it to the activity as shown below:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) R.id.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
textView.setText(result);
```

If you do this the value of result variable will be displayed in the textView region.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73586/discussion-on-answer-by-kesh1234-sqlite-query-returns-no-result).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following amended version of you code.You need to add a question mark after any equals sign in order to let the query function know what to bind to.

```
return db.query("LOGIN",new String[]{"ID","USERNAME","PASSWORD","COURSE","EMAIL","STUDENT_NAME"},"USERNAME =?, new String[]{username},null,null,null,null);
```

Comment: It doesn't even allow me to change activity now!! it says "Unfortunately Login_Final (name of the app) has stopped!!

Comment: I think the problem is that I don't have a text view in the activity to view the query results!! In that case what code modifications I have to do in order to combine the text view to the query?

Comment: Try the amended version above. I'm doing this from memory but the theory is right.